# Idempotent receiver - is there any equivalent to FilteringMessageListenerAdapter/RecordFilterStrategy for StreamListener

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I need to implement an idempotent listener using spring cloud stream kafka binder.

How could we wrap the StreamListener so that necessary filtering/de-duplication advice could be applied before messages are delegated to corresponding handlers?

Thanks.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `condition` on the `@StreamListener`; the only problem is the payload is not converted until the condition returns true. So you either need information in headers, or you would need to use native Kafka deserialization.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(Sink.class)
public class So53486162Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So53486162Application.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT, condition="@filter.shouldProcess(#root)")
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(KafkaTemplate<byte[], byte[]> template) {
        return args -> {
            template.send("so53486162", "dontProcessThisOne".getBytes());
            template.send("so53486162", "processThisOne".getBytes());
        };
    }

}

@Component
class Filter {

    public boolean shouldProcess(Message<byte[]> in) {
        String string = new String(in.getPayload());
        System.out.println("Filtering: " + string);
        return !string.equals("dontProcessThisOne");
    }

}
```

and

```
Filtering: dontProcessThisOne
2018-11-26 13:06:56.729  WARN 25874 --- [container-0-C-1] .DispatchingStreamListenerMessageHandler : 
    Cannot find a @StreamListener matching for message with id: null
Filtering: processThisOne
processThisOne
```